# Creating my own dialect thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm following the Thymeleaf documentation to create a processor and a dialect to change the css of the component when it is not filled. If it is not filled, add css class has error, but is not working.

I'm using Spring Boot

**Look class TagErrorAttributeProcessor**

```
public class TagErrorAttributeProcessor extends AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor {

    public TagErrorAttributeProcessor() {
        super("fielderror");
    }

    @Override
    public int getPrecedence() {
        return 12000;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getText(final Arguments arguments, final Element element, final String attributeName) {

        final Configuration configuration = arguments.getConfiguration();

        // Obtém o analisador de expressões padrão do Thymeleaf
        final IStandardExpressionParser parser = StandardExpressions.getExpressionParser(configuration);

        // Analisa o valor do atributo com uma expressão padrão do Thymeleaf
        final IStandardExpression expression = parser.parseExpression(configuration, arguments, element.getAttributeValue(attributeName));

        if (FieldUtils.hasErrors(arguments, element.getAttributeValue(attributeName))) {
            element.setAttribute("class", element.getAttributeValue("class") + " has-error");
        }
        // Executar expressão apenas para analisar
        final String execute = (String) expression.execute(configuration, arguments);


        return execute;
    }
}
```

**class TagErrorAttributeDialect**

```
public class TagErrorAttributeDialect extends AbstractDialect {

    @Override
    public String getPrefix() {
        return "rwfield";
    }

    @Override
    public Set<IProcessor> getProcessors() {
        final Set<IProcessor> processors = new HashSet<IProcessor>();
        processors.add(new TagErrorAttributeProcessor());
        return processors;
    }
}
```

**html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
        xmlns:rwfield="http://filedsErros"
        layout:decorator="'model/Layout/default'">

<div class="form-group" rwfield:fielderror="nome">
  <label for="LBUsuario">Nome:</label>
  <input id="nomUsr" type="text" th:field="*{nome}" class="form-control"/>
</div>
</html>
```